# Accessibility tab order for iOS keyboard with custom UI button

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I'm working on a cordova app that has a screen with an input text field that require a decimal iOS keypad.

I wasn't able to find a natural way to display the iOS keypad (that has only numbers and a period) from the javascript code.

As such, I used a cordova plugin (https://github.com/mrchandoo/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard) that uses the input attribute pattern="[0-9]*" to show the number pad (without the decimal) and creates a custom UI button, and positions it in the empty space.

It actually worked perfectly for me, until I started testing the component for accessibility.

When you're tabbing (i.e. swiping) in VoiceOver mode, that button cannot be accessed.

Is there any way I can somehow manipulate the tab order for iOS and insert my accessibility element?

Here's the (simplified) hybrid code: `<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" decimal="true">`

Here's the (simplified) native snippet:

```
decimalButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
[self setDecimalChar];
[decimalButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0 green:0/255.0 blue:0/255.0 alpha:1.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
decimalButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40.0];
[decimalButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[decimalButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressCancel:)
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];


decimalButton.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
[decimalButton setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(-20.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)];
[decimalButton setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed:210/255.0 green:213/255.0 blue:218/255.0 alpha:1.0]];
// locate keyboard view
UIWindow* tempWindow = nil;
NSArray* openWindows = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];

for(UIWindow* object in openWindows){
    if([[object description] hasPrefix:@"<UIRemoteKeyboardWindow"] == YES){
        tempWindow = object;
    }
}

UIView* keyboard;
for(int i=0; i<[tempWindow.subviews count]; i++) {
    keyboard = [tempWindow.subviews objectAtIndex:i];

    [self listSubviewsOfView: keyboard];
    decimalButton.frame = cgButton;
    [ui addSubview:decimalButton];
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you're getting the native number-pad and then overlaying a '.' UIButton on top of it?  Is it the '.' button that you can't swipe to?

Comment: @slugolicious yes exactly. I can't swipe to the subview that has custom UIButton.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is that the custom decimal button may not be automatically set as an accessibility element, which would mean that VoiceOver would not be able to interact with it.

The simplest way to test this would be to add

`[decimalButton setIsAccessibilityElement:YES];`

to the native code above.